# Running unit tests doesn't catch changes

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm going through the kotlin koans repo (https://github.com/kotlin/kotlin-koans).  Whenever I make changes to my .kt files and run the unit tests, the changes in the .kt files aren't reflected in the test results.  I've been getting around this by running `./gradlew build` before running the unit tests.

I'm using Android Studio as my IDE. Any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is bug in Android studio.
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-koans/issues/90
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18948

When you are running test, project doesn't recompile.
You should build project and then run tests again.